# Зачем ставят refresh токену время жизни +- 30 дней?

Tags: node.js

Зачем ставят refresh токену время жизни 30 дней? Если пара (access+refresh) меняется раз в 30(мин) Допустим она у access =30минут.И рефрештокен, который может жить 30 дней в итоге прожил 30минут.Или я что-то не понял, или можно ставить аксесу 30 минут , а рефрешу 31?

Comment: А вы уверены, что в эту самую минуту устройство будет включено и иметь доступ в интернет? Я вот не уверен

Comment: А, я кажется понял в чем суть) Спасибо)